# How can I catch and change the thrown exception message from facebook sdk?

Tags: php, facebook, exception

I'm getting this exception from facebook SDK:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: (#506) Duplicate status message thrown in [...] src/base_facebook.php on line 1033
```

How can I catch the exception before it prints this message?
I want to change it to something like this:

> *The response of the application still the same so we can't publish it in to your wall again : )*

Btw, there is a method (below) that handles all the exceptions and I want this new message only for that especific case.

```
protected function throwAPIException($result) {
    $e = new FacebookApiException($result);
    switch ($e->getType()) {
      // OAuth 2.0 Draft 00 style
      case 'OAuthException':
        // OAuth 2.0 Draft 10 style
      case 'invalid_token':
        $message = $e->getMessage();
      if ((strpos($message, 'Error validating access token') !== false) ||
          (strpos($message, 'Invalid OAuth access token') !== false)) {
        $this->setAccessToken(null);
        $this->user = 0;
        $this->clearAllPersistentData();
      }
    }

    throw $e;
  }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You put the code that is throwing the Exception within a `try` block and then catch it with a `catch` block:

```
try
{
  // Code goes here
}

catch (OAuthException $e)
{
  // Stuff to do with exception
}
```

Comment: Sure, but the problem is that there is a method that handles all the exceptions and the way you are talking the message will be displayed for all the exceptions.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. The above code will catch any `OAuthException` thrown from within the `try` block. Is that not what you want?

Comment: I want to catch only the "Duplicate status message" case. Do you see?

Comment: You need to catch every exception (or use `set_exception_handler`) or you'll get the fatal error above if one is uncaught. Do you want that? If you must filter based on type, within the `catch` block check to see `if (506 == $e->getCode())` (or whatever the exception code is).